# Azure devops pipeline testrun results to be updated in testrail

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jmeter, testrail

Hi we run the azure devops pipeline having all the test cases. We are using jmeter scripts to run and producing the run results for all the test cases. Is there any possibility that we could update these test results in TESTRAIL automatically after every run? Testrail is where we store our test cases.

Comment: why dont you store test cases in devops?

Answer (score 0):

TestRail has an [API](https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/getting-started/introduction/) so you should be able to submit results from JMeter directly, take a look at the [**Example POST Request**](https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/getting-started/accessing/)

```
POST /index.php?/api/v2/add_result/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.testrail.com
Content-Type: application/json

{ "status_id": 1 }
```

The equivalent JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler setup would be something like:

[image]

you will also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and configure it to send the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. This is a good way to start with.  This works fine when I  try to create a personal account for testrail and  I used the login credentials in HTTP Authorization manager of JMETER and I am able to post and get the test results. But the problem here is we are in enterprise edition and there is SSO associated with the account. So I don't have a password to login. In this case do you have any idea what to do